# How to read timed meta data from a live stream using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, metadata, wowza

I am running a stream from Wowza and I've implemented a module to insert metadata. How can I use JavaScript in the browser to read metadata attached to the http/rmtp stream? (I have both setup)